# Tile Grid Data storage for 3D Space in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

This question is (mostly) game engine independent but I have been unable to find a good answer.

I'm creating a turn-based tile game in 3D space using Unity. The levels will have slopes, occasional non-planar geometry, depressions, tunnels, stairs etc. Each level is static/handcrafted so tiles should never move. **I need a good way to keep track of tile-specific variables for static levels and i'd like to verify if my approaches make sense**.

My ideas are:

1. Create 2 Meshes - 1 is the complex game world, the second is a reference mesh overlay that will have minimal geometry; it will not be rendered and will only be used for the tiles. I would then Overlay the two and use the 2nd mesh as a grid reference.
2. Hard-code the tiles for each level. While tedious it will work as a brute force approach. I would, however, like to avoid this since it's not very easy to deal with visually.
3. Workaround approach - Convert the 3d to 2D textures and only use 1 mesh.
4. "Project" a plane down onto the level and record height/slope to minimize complexity. Also not ideal.
5. Create individual tile objects for each tile manually (non-rendered). Easiest solution i could think of.

Now for the **Unity3D specific question**:
Does unity allow selecting and assigning individual Verts/Triangles/Squares of a mesh and adding componenets, scripts, or variables to those selections; for example, selecting 1 square in the 10x10 unity plane and telling unity the square of that plane now has a new boolean attached to it? This question mostly refers to idea #1 above, where i would use a reference mesh for positional and variable information that were directly assigned to the mesh. I have a feeling that if i do choose to have a reference mesh, i'd need to have the tiles be individual objects, snap them in place using the reference, then attach relevant scripts to those tiles.

I have found a ton of excellent resources (like http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html) on tile generation (mostly procedural), i'm a bit stuck on the basics due to being new to unity and im not looking for procedural design.

Comment: Is each tile an object in the scene? If so, any reason not to put a script on it that has the tile-specific variables? I suppose I would lean towards #5. For the Unity-specific question, why are you selecting part of the mesh?

Comment: That's the question i'm essentially asking. Should i rely on individual tile objects instead of having one mesh. Can i even manipulate one mesh without adding extra components besides a Tile Script? Should i Hardcode where tile locations are and avoid having the overhead of extra objects in each scene?

"selecting part of the mesh" merely means targetting a grid directly. Even a unity plane is made up of a 10x10 grid, but i cannot individually target the vertices without special script behavior (it seems, i could be wrong).